# Meaning of "作ってくれた人達" in this sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning

I'm currently going through the Tobira book and at chapter 4 (読み物 section) there is this sentence:

(The context is an interview to a Japanese baseball player currently playing in USA)

> ...バッターが三振をした後に自分のバットを折ってしまったり、ピッチャーが打たれた後にグローブをロッカー投げたりするのを見ると驚く、**それを作ってくれた人達**のことを考えたら、僕にはそんなことは絶対に出来ないと言っている。

I understand that it says “the people who made it”, but what would be “it”? Is he talking about the people who made the equipment that is being damaged or the people who made it possible for them to play?

Also, the 打たれた part refers to the ball being hit and not the pitcher, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it refers to the people who made the equipment; the point is he can't disrespect the equipment when he thinks about the people who made it.

ピッチャーが打たれた means, in this case, that the pitcher "had his pitch hit" (in other words, the batter was able to hit it and he's annoyed; that's why he's throwing the glove).  Often the passive in Japanese carries a negative sentiment and this is an example.

To give a complete translation:  "What I'm saying is, when I see a batter strike out and break his bat, or a pitcher have his pitch hit and throw his glove, or whatever, I'm surprised.  When I think about the people who made the equipment, I could never do that."

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the full sentence translation, now I get it. 打たれた was kind of difficult to understand because it was just the verb in passive and I wasn’t sure if he was angry because he was hit (kind of weird but still possible) or was about the ball (his pitch) being hit since it was never mentioned.